# Integration path in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Given this integral 
$$I=\int_\gamma e^{-jk\rho \cos(\alpha-\phi)}d\alpha$$

and given that 
$k_x=k\cos\alpha $ is such that $k_x \in(-\infty, +\infty)$ 
and  $\phi \in [o, \pi]$

how can I obtain this picture?What's the meaning of the y-axis?

($\alpha$ is complex)

[image]

Comment: I struggle to understand your question: is the problem integrating that function along the path? By "What's the meaning of the y-axis" do you mean that it is not clear to you what the imaginary axis in the complex plane represents or something else?

Comment: @Chris I can't undestand how I can find the value $j \infty $ and $-j \infty $ starting from the condition on $k_x$... and the mathematical meaning of $j \infty $... what does it represent in this problem?

Comment: I think $j\infty$ and $-j\infty$ in your picture indicate that the curve on which to perform the integration goes to infinity in the $y$ direction, $j$ is often used in engineering to denote the imaginary unit more commonly indicated in mathematics with $i$, you don't have to "find them". (I'm assuming that the path in the picture is $\gamma$ in the integral)

Comment: @Chris It was told me "$\pm j\infty$" are the results of some calculations... but I can't understand (or guess :) ) how to do....

Comment: @Chris  could they come from the explicit expression of the complex cosine?